# How to proceed with Monticello package after renaming a package in Pharo 2.0

Tags: version-control, smalltalk, pharo, monticello

After renaming a Package/Category in Pharo 2.0 that is also under version control in a Monticello package of the same name, how to proceed?

- can i proceed with now renamed packages/categories in a Monticello package with an old, other name?
- can i rename Monticello packages accordingly with/without keeping the history intact?

What i ended up with for the moment is, loading the renamed Package/Category into a fresh image, creating a new Monticello package there and losing the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to rename a package I follow these steps:

1. Change the package name in Nautilus
2. Create a package in Monticello with the new name and commit it
3. Create a final and empty commit with the old package name and a comment giving the new name of the package

Comment: But do i not have to get rid of the old Monticello package somehow? I loaded the new Monticello packages into a fresh image after your procedure. If i kept working with the old image my packages seemed to be part of both, the new and the old Monticello package and the mechanism of marking them dirty seemed to mess up things i.e. i ended in a situation where my new package was marked clean even if there were changes - and i could not commit them..

Comment: I guess your situation is normal if your old package name is a prefix of your new package name. Monticello uses names to map categories to packages.